# Nested For loops and filtered data

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, autofilter

Greeting folks.

Looking for someone to point me in the right direction to help me continue my search for information… I think I am approaching the problem wrong and it may be my terminology or what I am searching for.

I am using one set of vba code to count specific values from a data dump and am using it to populate a grid/table on a ‘Tracker’ sheet (based on filters and conditions).

I have been able to get the number of matching values working correctly, using code like this:

```
LastRow = Sheets("Colums").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: vD14 = 0
For Each c1 In Sheets("Colums").Range("AC1:AC" & LastRow)
    If c1.Value = "Wired" Then
      vD14 = vD14 + 1
    End If
Next c1
    Sheets("Tracker-Import Data").Range("D14").Value = vD14  ‘paste the count value into D14 of this sheet
```

But am having trouble finding a way to ‘nest’ multiple conditions and count re-refined filter data.  As an example, I attempted to adjust the code above with some nesting, to drill down further, using this (which does not work).  EDIT EDIT - for clarification - the filter data is on multiple columns.  So 'wired' is in column AC and In-Progress might be in E.

```
'    LastRow = Sheets("Colum").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: vF13 =     0 'count items in col E
'    For Each c1 In Sheets("Colum,").Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
'        If c1.Value = "In-Progress" Then
'            For Each c2 In Sheets("Colum,").Range("AC1:AC" & LastRow)
'                If c2.Value = "Wired" Then
'                vF13 = vF13 + 1
'                End If
'            Next c2
'        End If
'    Next c1
'    Sheets("Tracker-Import and Data").Range("F13").Value = vF13
```

In a separate section of the code, I can already pull  advanced/auto filtered data and paste that data to a new sheet just fine.  I use this bit below to filter and paste rows onto a new/blank sheet, which also works:

```
With Sheets("Colums")
.Rows(1).Insert 'temporary "header" row to allow for subsequent Autofilter operations

 Set dataRng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion)
    With dataRng
    .Rows(1).Value = "temp header" ' assign temporary headers. no matter they actual value, since autofilter will use columns index
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="aaaa", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="bbb"
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="ccc" 
    .AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:="Wired"

     If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns("A")) > 1 Then    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(newTab1).Range("A2")
    .AutoFilter 'remove filters
     End With
    .Rows(1).Delete 'remove temporary "header" row
    Sheets("Colums").Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(newTab1).Range("A1")
```

I basically have two pieces of code now… and want to keep it that way:   One to populate table values on the ‘Tracker’ sheet, and another one to populate row/column data onto a NEW sheet created upon sub call.

The code that sends values to a new sheet is working just fine, but I am only getting partial success on populating the table values on the specific ‘Tracker’ sheet because of the need to ‘nest’ filters.  How do I add more advanced filtering to the first bit to count the refined values.

The only thing that I have found online that comes close to this scenario is this line, but I am not sure how to incorporate it correctly, with what I have (or if it is the right solution):
    Rowz = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

How can I modify the first block of code to have multiple nested conditions and COUNT those values?  I imagine I have to use something like this in the first block of code above, but I am not sure how to add in something like the autofilter code for a better For loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've got the question completely right but here are some comments:

To loop through a range and check multiple conditions I would loop on the rows instead of using **for each**

```
Sub test()

vF13 = 0
With Sheets("colums")
    LastRow = .Range("AC" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("E" & i).Value = "In Progress" And .Range("AC" & i).Value = "Wired" Then
        vF13 = vF13 + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
Sheets("Tracker-Import and Data").Range("F13").Value = vF13
End Sub
```

For autofilter you would put on an autofilter and then use the count function you listed above

```
Sub autofilter()
'clear autofilters from sheet
Sheets("sheet2").AutoFilterMode = False

With Sheets("sheet2")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
    'add 1 autofilter
    .autofilter field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    'add another autofulter
    .autofilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=3"
    'count rows
    visibleRows = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: amazing! Thank you.  The line "For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("E" & i).Value = "In Progress" And .Range("AC" & i).Value = "Wired" Then" seemed to address the direct issue of 'nesting' as I called it.   I will keep playing around with it, but it looks to have solved my brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off base here but it seems like you could just use an `If` statement with a counter in the last set of nesting.

Comment: I made a minor edit to the question/post above to mention that the nesting is reading across multiple columns.  So I would filter like the autofilter code, from column E, then maybe AC, then whichever else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific problem you have, I think you can solve it without the second loop, and just use the Offset method. (I used my fingers - E to AC is 24 right?)

```
LastRow = Sheets("Colum").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: vF13 = 0 'count items in col E
For Each c1 In Sheets("Colum,").Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
    If c1.Value = "In-Progress" And c1.Offset(0,24).Value = "Wired" Then
        vF13 = vF13 + 1
    End If
Next c1
Sheets("Tracker-Import and Data").Range("F13").Value = vF13
```